# Creating IOS app only using the command line of cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, code-signing-certificate

Which is not considered in [IOS Platform Guide of Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#signing-an-app). According to it, there should be some flags provided in order to create IOS app using command line. (the flags packageType is default `development` and the flag `codesingResourceRules` is optional; other 3 flags are discussed below)

As far as i see, there are two *possible* manners:

**1. Only using the flags --developmentTeam and --codeSignIdentity**

The documentation states:

> This is new for Xcode 8. The development team (Team ID) to use for
>   code signing. You would use this setting and a simplified Code Sign
>   Identity (i.e. just 'iPhone Developer') to sign your apps, you do not
>   need to provide a Provisioning Profile.

So, we have *developmentTeam* flag which is actually our TeamID that we can see in our Apple account. But in this case, it is unclear how to define codeSignIdentity without messing with XCode.

**2. Using ProvisioningProfile**

Second manner is by creating provisioning profile and by using its GUID. Again, it is not explained in cordova documentation and in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html) without using XCode.

So, the question is: is it not possible to create (debug or release) IOS app without using XCode? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

XCode is required. The [cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova) commandline uses XCode commands

```
cordova build ios --device --debug
```

You can choose --debug and --release

The details can be provided in a build.json file in the root of your project. See example content of the build.json file below.

```json
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "developmentTeam": "YOURTEAMID",
            "provisioningProfile":"12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
        },
        "release": {
            "developmentTeam": "YOURTEAMID",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "provisioningProfile": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there was a way to do this . 
For uploading to App store you need XCode for archiving .

I think if it was possible to build without XCode , there would be no need for MacOS .As it is mentioned it is required to build your app  .

Comment: Actually, cordova uses Xcode, but the command-line versions of the tools rather than the IDE.